# In visionOS, how does one change the Window glass color?

Tags: swiftui, visionos

For the Vision Pro, using the default app windows, how does one change the background color of the glass? I saw some apps had a blue background but I'm not seeing how to do it or at least maybe I am doing it but the simulator isn't showing it.

[image: Showing vision pro image of blue background.]

Comment: Maybe add an example or screenshot of the other app. Is it a native visionOS app or an iPad app running on visionOS?

Comment: @beyowulf I edited the question with the image. It looks to be a native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out using a ZStack like the following:

```
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60), style: .continuous))
                    .offset(z: -0.1)
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: windowSettings.WindowColor)
                
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```

The zstack puts the window color behind the glass so when you look through the glass you are seeing the color. Since it's a rectangle the corners exceed the glass so I rounded them just enough until they were hidden. You can do it more to make the color shrink to only the center if you wanted.

[image: Showing the colored window]

Comment: what is windowSettings?

Comment: @S.S.SaruarJahan Window settings is a custom object I made to publish the width and height of some windows. It doesn't relate to the above code and you can remove it with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this on the window itself but you can change the entire background color by setting the background color on your View:

```swift
@main
struct InkwellApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "mail-viewer") {
             ContentView()
                .background(.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        
    }
}
```

And then make the View take up all of the vertical and horizontal space using Spacers:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Spacer()                
                Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ExtractedView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

You can get a similar effect to what you shared in your image by using a background color with a smaller opacity value like this:

```
 .background(.blue.opacity(0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great and is an alternative to the way I figured out using zstacks.